# Ошибка в подключении к Бд

Tags: c#, sql

При подключении к БД на другом ПК выдает ошибку, по умолчанию строка подключения была:

[image]

Создавал папку с БД на другом ПК и указывал к ней путь, тоже не работает..

Выдает данную ошибку:

[image]
Нкжная версия на другом пк установленна.

Comment: А на другом пк localdb установлена?

Comment: да установлена  не знаю в чем проблема